# Triggers no MySQL com erros de "Unknown column" na chave de uma tabela onde são armazenadas essas triggers

Tags: trigger, mysql

Não estou entendo o porque desse erro de **Unknown column** em três triggers de uma mesma tabela, pois sempre aponta para as chaves e elas ao meu ver estão corretas.

**O erro vem proveniente da chave cd_venda da tabela venda**

A imagem das tabelas `itens_venda` e `venda` descritas nas triggers que são armazenadas em `itens_venda` são:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### São três triggers:

- O erro da trigger `itens_venda_AFTER_INSERT` é **Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'cd_venda' in 'NEW'**

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER itens_venda_AFTER_INSERT 
AFTER INSERT ON itens_venda 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    /* atualiza o valor total da venda ao adicionar o produto da compra */
    UPDATE venda SET valor_total = valor_total + (NEW.valor_item * NEW.quantidade_item) 
    WHERE cd_venda = NEW.cd_venda; -- Daqui vem o erro
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

- O erro da trigger `itens_venda_BEFORE_UPDATE` é **Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'cd_venda' in 'OLD'**

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER itens_venda_BEFORE_UPDATE 
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON itens_venda 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    /* Se for realizado a diminuição da quantidade de item da venda será registrado na tabela de devolução.*/
    IF OLD.status = 'Adicionado' THEN
        IF NEW.quantidade_item < OLD.quantidade_item THEN
            /* Atualiza o valor da venda quando diminui a quantidade do item */
            UPDATE venda SET valor_total = valor_total - (OLD.valor_item * (OLD.quantidade_item - 
            NEW.quantidade_item)) 
            WHERE cd_venda = OLD.cd_venda; -- Daqui vem o erro
        END IF;
    END IF;
END$
DELIMITER ;
```

- O erro da trigger `itens_venda_AFTER_UPDATE` é **Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'cd_venda' in 'OLD'**

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER itens_venda_AFTER_UPDATE
AFTER UPDATE 
ON itens_venda
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    /* Atualiza o valor total se o produto for cancelado */
    IF NEW.status = 'Cancelado' THEN
        UPDATE venda SET valor_total = valor_total - (OLD.valor_item * OLD.quantidade_item) 
        WHERE cd_venda = OLD.cd_venda; -- Daqui vem o erro
    END IF;
END$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Mas o campo `cd_venda` não existe em `itens_venda` o nome mais próximo é o campo `cd_itens_venda`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques vou olhar aqui se é isso mesmo.

Comment: Onde está `WHERE cd_venda = OLD.cd_venda` troque para `WHERE cd_venda = OLD.cd_itens_venda`

Comment: @AugustoVasques deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: @AugustoVasques responde ai pergunta pra eu marca sua resposta como a melhor.

Comment: WHERE cd_venda = OLD.cd_itens_venda certo, o restante que possui o NEW vai ser a mesma coisa?

Comment: Sim a mesma coisa.

Comment: Tipo ```WHERE cd_venda = NEW.cd_itens_venda``` nas duas primeiras triggers?

Comment: Se o campo `cd_itens_venda` sofreu alteração use `NEW.cd_itens_venda`  
 caso não tenha havido alteração mantenha `OLD.cd_itens_venda`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O campo `cd_venda` não existe na tabela `itens_venda` por isso os erros dentro dos triggers.

Refaça os relacionamentos entre chave primária `vendas.cd_venda` com a chave estrangeira `itens_venda.cd_itens_venda`.

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER itens_venda_AFTER_INSERT 
AFTER INSERT ON itens_venda 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    /* atualiza o valor total da venda ao adicionar o produto da compra */
    UPDATE venda SET valor_total = valor_total + (NEW.valor_item * NEW.quantidade_item) 
    WHERE cd_venda = NEW.cd_itens_venda; 
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

---

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER itens_venda_BEFORE_UPDATE 
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON itens_venda 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    /* Se for realizado a diminuição da quantidade de item da venda será registrado na tabela de devolução.*/
    IF OLD.status = 'Adicionado' THEN
        IF NEW.quantidade_item < OLD.quantidade_item THEN
            /* Atualiza o valor da venda quando diminui a quantidade do item */
            UPDATE venda SET valor_total = valor_total - (OLD.valor_item * (OLD.quantidade_item - 
            NEW.quantidade_item)) 
            WHERE cd_venda = OLD.cd_itens_venda;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE TRIGGER itens_venda_AFTER_UPDATE
AFTER UPDATE 
ON itens_venda
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    /* Atualiza o valor total se o produto for cancelado */
    IF NEW.status = 'Cancelado' THEN
        UPDATE venda SET valor_total = valor_total - (OLD.valor_item * OLD.quantidade_item) 
        WHERE cd_venda = OLD.cd_itens_venda;
    END IF;
END$
DELIMITER ;
```